# How to use FMDB in background with SQLCipher?

Tags: fmdb, sqlcipher

I have some problems to make my queries in the background.

I download a JSON from internet, parse it with Reskit and save an array of objects with FMDB into my sqlite3 database encrypted with SQLCipher.

This is an example:

```
FMDatabaseQueue *_queueSelect = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:[DataBaseController getPathBaseDatos]];

    [_queueSelect inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

        [db setKey:DATABASE_KEY];

        FMResultSet *existeConsulta = [db executeQuery:sql];
            while([existeConsulta next]) {

                [results addObject:[existeConsulta resultDictionary]];

            }
    }];
```

I tried to use "inTransaction"
and "dispatch_async"
but without success.

What is the right way to do this task?

Comment: What do you mean "without success"? Did it run successfully, but just not asynchronously? (That makes sense, as this code snippet doesn't do anything asynchronously.) Or did it fail? If it failed, did you check the return codes of `setKey` and of `executeQuery`? Were they `TRUE` and non-`nil` respectively? If either failed, what was `lastErrorMessage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run this asynchronously, `FMDatabaseQueue` doesn't do this asynchronous operation for you, but just gives you a framework so that when you interact with this queue from multiple threads, the interaction will be synchronized for you.

So, one would (a) instantiate a single `FMDatabaseQueue` object for the entire app; and (b) when you want to run something asynchronously, you have to run that from a background dispatch or operation queue.

For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT), ^{
    [_queueSelect inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        // do your stuff here
    }];
});
```